# python iterating over a very large file stream

Tags: python, parsing, popen

I'm not an experienced python coder, so be gentle.

I have a very large (100s of Gb) binary file, that requires a particular command line tool (called parseTool here) to parse it.   The format of the output of parseTool is simple raw text that I am doing some basic processing of (counting values, etc.).

Before I think about running multiple instances of my code on a cluster I want to make sure I am doing things reasonably efficiently.

Here is what I am using to iterate over the output of parseTool:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(procTool +' myFile.file ',
                        shell=True,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in proc.stdout:
    linep=line.split("\t")
    #process each line until end of stream
```

To be clear, my main concern is efficiently iterating over the output of parseTool.   Any helpful tips out there?

Comment: Why do you use `shell=True`?

Comment: This is the normal way to do pipelining and is efficient as long as you don't let too much state build up in your process (e.g., keeping a list that blows up after a few tens of gigs of data). Sometimes there is a benefit to using an intermediate file (you can reprocess, for instance), but this way should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is perfectly fine and will "stream" the data efficiently, assuming that the "parseTool" also streams properly and that the text output does not have really long lines.

**If** it did have long lines (in particular, ones that scale as the input does, rather than having some upper bound) then you would want to take care to read chunks smaller than a line rather than reading a whole line and then splitting it.

Comment: Thanks. The lines are dependably less than 1000 characters.

Answer (score -1):

You say your file is in binary.

If you use:

```
for line in proc.stdout:
    ...
```

Then the interpreter will read the binary data until it finds a new line character.

Since you said "binary", this seams to be a bad solution.

I would read in fixed chunks:

```
max_length=1024

while True:
    chunk=proc.stdout.read(max_length)
    if not chunk:
        break
    print chunk
```

Comment: While the original input file is binary, the OP says the output of `parseTool` is text, so reading by line is perfectly fine.